# Hibernate logging too much information

Tags: hibernate, log4j, logging

I have following information in log4j.properties file..

```
log4j.appender.file = org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File = C:\\app\\file.log
log4j.appender.file.Threshold = TRACE
log4j.appender.file.DatePattern = '.'yyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.file.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern = %d %5p [%C:%M:%L] - %m%n
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, file
#HIbernate logging
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL = DEBUG, file
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type = TRACE, file
log4j.additivity.org.hibernate.SQL = false
```

Problem with this configuration is that it is writing too much of information to log file and the file is growing into MBs with in a short time. So I was wondering if there is anything I can do to stop hibernate messing up the log file and write only sql select statement and parameters and nothing else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of really verbose and not intuitive hibernate SQL logging you can use a Pass through Java JDBC driver that can log `SQL` and/or `JDBC calls` for other JDBC drivers.

Pass through JDBC driver have the advantage that the logged output, for prepared statements, have the bind arguments automatically inserted into the SQL output. This greatly Improves readability, debugging and the size of the log for many cases. SQL timing information can be generated when needed.

With hibernate's logging you have logging similar to :

```
 select bs0_.A_REF as A2_7_0_ from B bs0_ where  bs0_.other = 0 and bs0_.A_REF=?  
 TRACE 2011-08-  03 00:30:45,317 binding '123' to parameter: 1
```

With big query with a lot of parameter it can be painfull to replace all the bind parameter before executing the query manually on the database.

With Pass through JDBC driver you have logging similar to :

```
select bs0_.A_REF as A2_7_0_ from B bs0_ where  bs0_.other = 0 and bs0_.A_REF=123
```

All the bind parameter are resolved and you just have to copy paste it to execute the query on the database.

You can check [log4jdbc](http://code.google.com/p/log4jdbc/) as good pass through JDBC driver.
To shut off hibernate logging be sure to set to false the `hibernate.show_sql` properties in the config file and all SQL related logger. See the [Logging Configuration](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-logging) section of the reference documentation

Comment: Thanks a lot Joel.. I followed your advice and used log4jdbc driver and had this property set `log4j.logger.jdbc.sqlonly = DEBUG` are there are any other properties that can be useful ?

Comment: I set the `log4j.logger.jdbc.sqlonly=INFO` DEBUG is too verbose by including the class name and line number and it imposes an additional performance penalty when in use. If you add the `log4jdbc.properties` file in the class path and set the properties `log4jdbc.dump.sql.maxlinelength=7000` you can have one SQL statement by line in the console.

Comment: @Joel.. it's not working for me.. I added these two lines in log4jdbc.properties files and placed it under web-inf/classes `log4jdbc.debug.stack.prefix = com.abcd log4jdbc.dump.sql.maxlinelength=7000`.. sql statements are still in multiple lines and the first property is also not used in determining the call sequence

Comment: @rrkwells If it's can help I am using the `1.2beta2` version and the jar `log4jdbc4-1.2beta2.jar` is under `WEB-INF/lib`. You can try to set it as a `-DSystem propery log4jdbc.dump.sql.maxlinelength=7000`